# Calculating a file line by line: EOF repeating the last number (can't use breaks)

Tags: c++, fstream, eof

This is supposed to be a very simple program. My issue is that the last number repeats itself, and I fully understand this because EOF is not reached until I get back inside the loop and read the number, which, at that time, is too late. I can get around this by doing something like, "If (!fileIn) break; count++" after I put "fileIn >> num" in the for loop(and if (count > 1), I would get into the last block of code that calculates average, outputs total, average, etc.). Only problem is that my professor doesn't want breaks in this program, so I'm just trying to see how else to solve it.

Thanks.

INPUT FILE:

346 130 982 90  656 117 595

415 948 126 4   558 571 87

42  360 412 721 463 47  119

441 190 985 214 509 2   571

77  81  681 651 995 93  74

310 9   995 561 92  14  288

466 664 892 8   766 34  639

151 64  98  813 67  834 369

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int NumPerLine = 7;

int main()
{

int num = 0;
int total = 0;
float average = 0;
int min = 0;
int max = 0;

ifstream fileIn;

fileIn.open("File2.txt");
ofstream fileOut("Output.txt");

if (!fileIn) {

cout << "/nError opening file...Closing program. n";
exit(1);
}

while (fileIn) {

cout << endl;

int total = 0;
int count = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < NumPerLine; k++) {

    fileIn >> num;

    if (k == 0) {
    max = num;
    min = num;
    }

    total += num;
    cout << num << " ";
    fileOut << num << " ";

    if (num > max)
    max = num;

    if (num < min)
    min = num;

}

average = total / NumPerLine;

cout << "/n/nTotal is " << total << "." << endl;
cout << "Average is " << average << "." << endl;
cout << "Lowest number is " << min << endl;
cout << "Largest number is " << max << endl;

fileOut << "/n/nTotal is " << total << "." << endl;
fileOut << "Average is " << average << "." << endl;
fileOut << "Lowest number is " << min << endl;
fileOut << "Largest number is " << max << endl << endl;
}


fileIn.close();
fileOut.close();

cout << "/nData has been processed, and copied to the file, " Output.txt "." << endl << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys!! Also, thank you to the guy who told me to change my while loop to while(!fileIn.eof()) who then deleted their answer. That was the quickest and simplest fix - Just so I know in the future, can someone tell me why it gets to the end of file before while(fileIn) does?

Comment: Your professor seems to be preaching a break-free doctrine that doesn't accord with common practice in the IT industry. He shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working with a while loop, you may use a `do/while` (specially because of initial non NULL check):

```
do {

cout << endl;

int total = 0;
int count = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < NumPerLine; k++) {

    fileIn >> num;

    if (k == 0) {
    max = num;
    min = num;
    }

    total += num;
    cout << num << " ";
    fileOut << num << " ";

    if (num > max)
    max = num;

    if (num < min)
    min = num;

} while(fileIn);
```

Comment: As the check hapoens after the input was processed rather the between reading and processing, the change doesn't help: it is necessary to check after reading and before processing the values.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I suppose you mean needed check after first read in for loop, am I wrong? I agree that it should be check but I only wanted to show what I meant by replacing while by do/while.

Comment: You also need to check *after* reading and *before* doing any thing with the result: the stream can't know whether a tead will succeed. However, it will know if a read did succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Always check the state of the stream **after** you attempted to read it: if the input failed the stream is nut into failure mode (i.e. `std::ios_base::failbit` is set) and the stream converts to `false`.